# How to import jar files in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans-8, sphinx4

I am trying to build a very basic voice recognition application via a tutorial. I need to add sphinx4-core.jar and sphinx4-data.jar. I added them into my library and am attempting to import them into my code and I get a "package edu.cmu.sphinx.api does not exist" error. Here are my import statements:

```
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Configuration;    
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.LiveSpeechRecognizer;
import edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechResult;
```

To add the jar files I went to tools -> libraries -> add JAR/Folder

Comment: You are trying to add wrong jars probably. You need the ones with 5prealpha.

Comment: The sphinx jar that I added to my library is 5prealpha.

Comment: They should have different name then, not sphinx4-core.jar